# subprocess calls inside async function not happening in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to do two levels of "asynchronousness" in my application.

Say my input data is:

```
input = {
    "set1": ["subset11", "subset12"],
    "set2": ["subset21", "subset22"],
    ...
}
```

And I need to process them in such a way:

- Process all sets in parallel
- Within each set, process subsets in parallel, then do some summarization

So I am doing:

```
# top level function
async def process_all_sets(input):
    tasks = [process_set(payload) for key, payload in input.items()]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

# process a single set    
async def process_set(payload):
    tasks = [process_subset(item) for item in payload]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    # here, loop over results and do some summarization
    # and return it
    return summary

# process a single subset
async def process_subset(subset):
    # need to run a subprocess here, it make take several minutes
    subprocess.run("some_command_based_on_subset")
    # do whatever needs to be done after subprocess completes
    # and return result
    return result
```

Since `asyncio` is supposed to run multiple calls of `process_subset` in parallel within a set, I am expecting to see several `subprocess.run` calls get called at the same time. But I am only seeing one call happening at a time.

Where's the parallelization then?

Comment: `subprocess.run` is blocking

Comment: Yeah @juanpa.arrivillaga .. but it is blocking "within" a call of `process_subset` function right? So multiple calls to `process_subset` should invoke multple `subprocess.run` calls? No?

Comment: asyncio doesn't run things in parallel. It uses cooperative multitasking; when a task is waiting (e.g., for I/O) it can yield to another task that has processing to do. When you make a blocking call, your task is still the active task and it has to wait for the call to complete before it can yield to any other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. I switched from `subprocess.run` to `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` and it works as expected now!

```
# process a single subset
async def process_subset(subset):
    # need to run a subprocess here, it make take several minutes
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell("some_command_based_on_subset")
    await process.wait()
    # do whatever needs to be done after subprocess completes
    # and return result
    return result
```